# Asp.net : How to deny a page to be accesed by users and set permissions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have some asp.net pages , and I want to deny them to be accessed by direct link .
So I need to make a page to by accessed only by administrators and a page that will be accesed by logged users.

How can I do that? can someone explain or show a good example?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can create a folder with pages that needs to be accessed by set of users. Inside the folder you can create **web.config** with restriction.

```
eg.<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="user1,user2" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You can find more about [ASP.NET Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301390.aspx)

**Update**

On successful login you can add the users to a specific role.

eg. you assigned to the role **users**

then you can modify the `web.config`

```
 <authorization> 
            <allow roles="users" />
            <deny users="*" /> 
  </authorization>
```

Comment: well ,as I can see deny users , so that's how you deny specific users , I need to deny all users who are not logged.

Comment: ok so basically it will allows only users with the role"users"but what does roles="user" means? a table data called users or ?

Comment: @InaaInzii : Try to find something by your self as well. Don't expect others to complete your task. Anyway you can find about user membership and user roles here 
**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx** and 
**http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx**